# I need to get last part of string in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Hello I need to get ID key, which is in the href part, like that

```
<a href="/offer/something-is-verz-incorrect-1bMo.html"> some text </a>
```

and i need to get with xsl 1bMo to variable.

I try something like that:

```
<xsl:variable name="job_id3" select="str:split(substring-before(@href,'.html'), '-')[last()]"/>
<xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="concat($ADAPTER_ID, '/', $job_id3)"/></xsl:attribute>
```

My XML output must look like this:

```
   <job id="adapter/1bMo"">
      <str name="source">some source</str>
      <str name="title">some title</str>
...
...
   </job>
```

Now my XML output look like this, and this is wrong:

```
   <job id="adapter/something-is-verz-incorrect-1bMo">
      <str name="source">some source.sk</str>
      <str name="title">some title</str>
...
...
   </job>
```

but it make error: The URI http://exslt.org/strings does not identify an external Java class. I dont know how to fix it, any ideas how I can get 1bm9 from every href?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for my problem is here:

```
<xsl:template name="substring-after-last">
        <xsl:param name="input" />
        <xsl:param name="marker" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($input,$marker)">
                <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
                    <xsl:with-param name="input"
          select="substring-after($input,$marker)" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="marker" select="$marker" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$input" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

and call template:

```
<xsl:attribute name="job_id">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($ADAPTER_ID, '/')"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="substring-after-last">
                  <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$job_id2" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="marker" select="'-'" />
            </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:attribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSLT 2.0 and assuming the id will always follow the last dash, you can use [tokenize](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-tokenize):

```
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize(substring-before(/a/@href,'.html'),'-')[last()]"/>
```

Input

```
<a href="/offer/something-is-verz-incorrect-1bMo.html"> some text </a>
```

Output

```
1bMo
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build the variable with this XPath:

```
substring-before(substring(/a/@href,string-length(/a/@href) - 8),'.')
```

But it assumes that the href always ends with ".html", and the ID key is always 4 characters, so this might not be any use at all :)